# How to send commands (strings) from an Android device over to an ESP8266?

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 hooked up to an MCU on a PCB.

I would like to send commands (strings) from my Android phone over to the ESP8266 so it can, in turn, transfer them to the MCU so it can perform various tasks.

How can this be done? I am looking into creating an app for the Android device using MIT's app inventor.

Comment: Try google translator and understand the quirks of AT over ESP8266  http://labdegaragem.com/forum/topics/conhecendo-o-esp8266?commentId=6223006%3AComment%3A501212  with more http://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/documents?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Where did you find info about communication over WIFI with the ESP8266 in there? I have it setup communicating with the MCU over UART and AT commands work as should.

Comment: I'm unclear what it is that you are having problems with.

Comment: @Andyaka Edited

Comment: Search for WiFi on that page, lots of info and links

Comment: There appear to be plenty of google links to sending and receiving from and to an ESP8266 - are you wanting to send an SMS message to your android for instance?

Comment: @Andyaka I want to have an app with about 5 to 10 buttons that the user clicks and it send data over to the ESP8266 - that's all. No need to get data back and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I just know one methodology. Using the wifi module, MCU should connect to the home network. TCP/IP Server has to be coded in MCU and it should listen for client connections. Android App will be TCP/IP Client which connects to this server. After connecting, the app or client can send TCP/IP data over air. MCU code will read this data and do necessary things like switching on LEDs etc.